# Strict Text Formats in SharePoint Online

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, custom-list, column, validation

In my SharePoint Online list I have column `Serial#` and I want **Serial#** in a specific format like `5CB34307L8, 2CE0031NWX`
For example if I type 512,bc1 it should be converted automatically  into 512BC1 when i go to next field.

I want my Serial# containing

- Only uppercase letters
- Only digits
- Without space, commas and any wild characters
- Serial lengths can be variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can write Calculated Formulas to do Column Validation;
the result needs to be a TRUE or FALSE value

[image]

For example:

```
=UPPER([column])=[column]
```

Returns true when the entry is all Uppercase

```
=AND( UPPER([column])=[column] , NOT(FIND(" ",[column])) )
```

returns FALSE if the entry contains a space as well

All (Excel like) Functions you can use in SharePoint are listed at: https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List